# check if all actions are finished cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

My problem is this: i do quite a bit of code in `ccTouchEnded` and i want for the `CCTouchDispacher` to stop all input until all actions on the screen are over. The thing is that when i tap the screen repeatedly `ccTouchEnded` gets called every timeand it ruins everything. I've tried to stop the input but i don't know which of the actions will execute..so i can't just run a `CCSequence` and when it's finished re-enable input.

My code looks something like this:

```
if (taped in a rect)..do action, change some things around,do another action, call method 1
if (condition)..do action,check something,(if (check) do action, else call method 2)
```

Its worth noting that the methods do different things in different layers which take different amounts of time.

So my question is this: Is there any way to check if all actions on the screen are completed?

Comment: are you aware of CCCallFunc action ?

Comment: of course..but as i said...i don't know which of the actions will execute ..and it'll be very weird to call it 20 times thorough my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the number of running actions on the node/sprite/layer is zero:

http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCNode.html#//api/name/numberOfRunningActions

Such as:

`[mySprite numberOfRunningActions]==0`

Answer (score 0):

You have the isDone function that tells you if an CCAction is finished. From the docs:

> (BOOL) - isDone return YES if the action has finished